# Struggling with removing outliers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, outliers

I'm doing the Udacity intro to ML course and I'm having some trouble with this exercise (Lesson 8 Quiz 12).

The question is as follows:

> In outliers/outlier_cleaner.py, you will find the skeleton for a
>   function called outlierCleaner() that you will fill in with a cleaning
>   algorithm. It takes three arguments: predictions is a list of
>   predicted targets that come from your regression, ages is the list of
>   ages in the training set, and net_worths is the actual value of the
>   net worths in the training set. There should be 90 elements in each of
>   these lists (because the training set has 90 points in it). Your job
>   is to return a list called cleaned_data that has only 81 elements in
>   it, which are the 81 training points where the predictions and the
>   actual values (net_worths) have the smallest errors (90 * 0.9 = 81).
>   The format of cleaned_data should be a list of tuples, where each
>   tuple has the form (age, net_worth, error).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np

p_test = np.array([1,2,3,4,50])
a_test = np.array([32,31,44,22,20])
n_test = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])

def outlierCleaner(predictions, ages, net_worths):
    """
        clean away the 10% of points that have the largest
        residual errors (different between the prediction
        and the actual net worth)

        return a list of tuples named cleaned_data where 
        each tuple is of the form (age, net_worth, error)
    """

    cleaned_data = []

    differences = predictions - net_worths

    cleaned_data = zip(ages, net_worths, differences)

    cleaned_data = sorted(cleaned_data, key=lambda x: x[2][0], reverse=True)

    limit = int(len(net_worths)*0.1)

    predictions.sort(axis=0)
    net_worths.sort(axis=0)


    return cleaned_data[limit:]

print(outlierCleaner(p_test,a_test,n_test))
```

It took me a while to figure out to use the `zip()` function. As far as I can see, this should be returning my list with 4 elements from my `a_test[]` list.

However I'm getting an error that I'm struggling to debug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/xxx/Documents/udacity_ml/python3/ud120-projects/outliers/outlier_cleaner.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(outlierCleaner(p_test,a_test,n_test))   File "/Users/xxx/Documents/udacity_ml/python3/ud120-projects/outliers/outlier_cleaner.py", line 25, in outlierCleaner
    cleaned_data = sorted(cleaned_data, key=lambda x: x[2][0], reverse=True)   File "/Users/xxx/Documents/udacity_ml/python3/ud120-projects/outliers/outlier_cleaner.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    cleaned_data = sorted(cleaned_data, key=lambda x: x[2][0], reverse=True) IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: I don't know `numpy` and its classes, but from the error message it looks like you should replace `lambda x: x[2][0]` with `lambda x: x[2]` (the `key` argument to `sorted()` must be formulated for a single element of the sequence).

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I'm still not fully sure I understand how lambda functions work and why I need to sort for a single element of the sequence though. Could someone be kind enough to ELI5 on this one, while I go about trying to research it myself?